# Nginx not redirecting some location to php

Tags: php, nginx

On my site conf I have:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|ico|js|gif|jpe?g|png|less|txt)$ {
    etag on;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 180d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

But then I try to access `http://my-site-url/images/profiles/uid-of-my-image.jpg` It's not being redirecting to php, where I have a script that generates this image.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be redirected to your PHP block if it doesn't have a PHP extension? If you're relying on your `try_files` in the root location, and it doesn't find anything, it'll revert to `index.php?$args`. But since the URI didn't have any arguments, it'll just show the index page

Comment: But it is not showing the index, it is showing the nginx 404 page.

Comment: That might be because it's falling into your static files location block. Try adding either a `root` directive specifying where the static files live along with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` in your second location block that you've provided.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: Sure. I'll add is as an answer. Please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `root` directive specifying where the static files live along with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` in your second location block that you've provided. Below is a sample config:

```
...

location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|ico|js|gif|jpe?g|png|less|txt)$ {

root /absolute/path/to/static/files;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

etag on;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
expires 180d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
}

...
```